# Plot linear relation shapes in R similar to the following picture

Tags: r

I wonder if one knows an R package that I can produce the following figures separately.

[image]how

Comment: You really need to clarify your question. Is it about plotting or having them separate?  It really would help if you post what kind of R code you were using or intend to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make beautiful plots by using functions directly with ggplot2. Here is my first attempt for your first plot.

```
library("ggplot2")
f <- function(x) 0 + (1*x) - (1*x*x)
tmp <- data.frame(x=0:1, y=f(0:1))

# Make plot object
p <- qplot(x, y, data=tmp, xlab="X-axis", ylab="Y-axis") 
p <- p + stat_function(fun=f) + theme_pub()
p <- p + annotate("text", label = "Inverted U-shape/quadratic model", x = .5, y = .40, size = 6)
p + annotate("text", label = "Decreasing returns \n y = x + x + z", x = .5, y = .34, size = 6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to plot the figure layout first and than add a curve with your function

```
plot(x = c(0, 100), y = c(0, 100), type = "n")
curve("your function", 0, 100, add = T)
```

The 0 and 100 in the `curve` means for which values curve should be drawn.

Example:

```
plot(x = c(0, 100), y = c(0, 10), type = "n")
curve(0.2 + 0.1 * x, 0, 100, add = T)
```

[image]

Comment: `curve` doesn't need `plot` first.

Comment: of course it does not need, but it helps if you want to keep the scales over several figures

Comment: Use `xlim` and `ylim` in `curve`.

Comment: You can use `par` and argument `mfrow`: `par(mfrow=c(2,2)); curve(sin, 0, 10); curve(cos, 0, 10); curve(tan, 0, 10); curve(tanh, 0, 10)`.

Comment: @Pascal is absolutely right. I just thought about a single plot out of the picture OP presented

Comment: You can also use `plot` directly on a closure: `plot(function(x) 1 + (1*x) - (1*x*x))` (Example for the first plot)